# reCAPTCHA4j does not work in a SSL context (Certificate issue)

Tags: ssl, captcha, recaptcha

I was using recaptcha4j plugin in my webapp but now i need to make secure the app through SSL context. This step has caused some problems for me. The recaptcha is not shown because the challenge https://api-secure.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=........ is not valid due to certificate issues because reCaptcha SSL Api was changed in 2011: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/V7qswqBnA1o

For this reason, i have to face this problem using the api directly. Is it possible to use a plugin similar to recaptcha4j or i have to implement the recaptcha with something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=your_public_key">
</script>
<noscript>
   <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=your_public_key"
       height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
   <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
   </textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
       value="manual_challenge">
</noscript>
```

In the java method, do i have to use the api directly doing a POST to verify the captcha? https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify or is it exist another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSP/JAVA reCaptcha plugin is not updated and google changed the secure URL. It's mandatory to use recaptcha in JAVA without plugins.

Answer (score 0):

There's an upgraded version of the library (0.0.8) that solves the problem. View [here](https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha4j/issues/detail?id=7).

If you use Maven you'll have to update the dependency, because it was repackaged.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.net.tanesha.recaptcha4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>recaptcha4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```